# Trouble creating a node which includes a range

Tags: neo4j

I am working on making the framework for a music recommendation system (with data from Million Songs in a CSV file) by connecting songs in a graph database using neo4j. This is my first time using neo4j, but I have used SQL before.

So far I have three nodes: Song, Artist, and Tempo.

I have already created the relationship between artists and their songs, and now I'm trying to create a relationship between each song and a range of tempos.

I could just have each song have a relationship to a specific tempo (ex: 120bpm), however that would not be very useful since I would not then be able to backtrack from Tempo and see another song that's very close in speed (ex: 119 or 121bpm).

Therefore, I'm attempting to group my Tempo nodes (which are floats) from being one exact number (ex:120bpm) to a range such as 0-80 (classified as very slow), 81-100 (slow), 101-130 (moderate), ... etc.

I know it would theoretically be better not to have set groups of tempos, but I'm just beginning and it will be ok for now.

Each Song node has parameters `title` `artistName` `tempo`.

Each Artist node has parameters `artistName` `title`.

Each Tempo node has parameters `tempo` `title`.

I have tried using creating a new node via:

```
CREATE (Tempo {Tempo.tempo<80});
```

... and several other ways I can't remember right now. Anyone that knows how to do this or if it's possible?

Comment: I'm not quite following how you want the properties on the :Tempo nodes to look. Is it something like this, as an example of a :Tempo node?  `(:Tempo {tempo:'<80'})` Is the tempo property supposed to be a string? Or do you want to have something like two separate numeric properties for the lower and upper bound? Or something else?

Comment: Two separate numeric properties is what I was looking for. I was trying to write it as an equality, but I think using `min` and `max` like cybersam did in his response could be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be duplicating properties unnecessarily across multiple node labels, in a way that would prevent a given node from being related to multiple other nodes. For example, an Artist node should not have a title property, since that would tie that node to a specific Song. Every Song would presumably have a relationship to the appropriate Artist anyway, so there is no need to store the song's title in the Artist node.

Also, as @InverseFalcon suggested, you can represent a range by using a pair of properties, say `min` and `max`.

Here is an example of a path in a suitable data model:

```
(:Tempo {min: 0, max: 79})<-[:HAS_TEMPO]-(:Song {title: 'Foo'})<-[:PERFORMED]-(:Artist {name: 'Fred'})
```

There would be one `Tempo` node for each tempo range.

Using the above data model, this simple query will return all songs that have the same tempo range (`$speed` is a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/) indicating the specific tempo of interest):

```
MATCH (t:Tempo)
WHERE t.min <= $speed <= t.max
MATCH (t)<-[:HAS_TEMPO]-(s:Song)
RETURN s;
```

And this is how you'd return the distinct artists who have ever performed a song in the desired tempo range:

```
MATCH (t:Tempo)
WHERE t.min <= $speed <= t.max
MATCH (t)<-[:HAS_TEMPO]-(:Song)<-[:PERFORMED]-(a:Artist)
RETURN DISTINCT a;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the kind of hint I needed. I had commented a couple questions but I have deleted them since I worked them out after a while. Thanks again!